# regular expression \b in java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex

Is there any difference of use regular expression \b in java and js?
I tried below test:
in javascript:

```
console.log(/\w+\b/.test("test中文"));//true
```

in java:

```
String regEx = "\\w+\\b";
text = "test中文";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("matched");//never executed
}
```

Why the result of the two example above are not same?

Comment: Javascript regexes don't understand unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because by default [Java supports Unicode for `\b` but not for `\w`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), while JavaScript doesn't support Unicode for both.

So `\w` can only match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters (in our case `test`) but `\b` can't accept place (marked with `|`)

```
test|中文
```

as between alphabetic and non-alphabetic Unicode standards because both `t` and `中` are considered alphabetic characters by Unicode.

If you want to have `\b` which will ignore Unicode you can use [look-around mechanism](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and rewrite it as `(?:(?<=\\w)(?!\\w)|(?<!\\w)(?=\\w))`, or in case of this example simple `(?!\\w)` instead of `\\b` will also work.

If you want `\w` to also support Unicode compile your pattern with `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag (which can also be written as flag expression `(?U)`)

Comment: +1. Note that you don't usually want or need to write all of `(?:(?<=\\w)(?!\\w)|(?<!\\w)(?=\\w))`, since in almost any context, some part of it will be redundant. In the OP's case, the non-Unicode version of `\\b` is just `(?!\\w)`.

Comment: Additionally, in Java, `\b` is not sync with definition of `\w`. `\b` by default is `_` plus `Character.isLetterOrDigit()` (which is Unicode aware, but this implementation is incorrect), and in `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` mode, will sync with definition of `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

The Jeva regex looks for a sequence of word characters, i.e. `[a-zA-Z_0-9]+` preceding a word boundary. But 中文 doesn't fit `\w`. If you use `\\b` alone, you'll find two matches: begin and end of the string.

As has been pointed out by georg, Javascript isn't interpreting characters the same way as Java's Regex engine.

Comment: That's actually strange, because a word boundary is supposed to be on the boundary between `\w` and `\W`. Since `test` matches `\w+` and `中文` matches `\W+` there should have been a `\b` there.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Java's regex engine has had problems in earlier releases as well. Here, `text` matches `"\\w+\\W+"`, but not `"\\w+\\b"`, which is contrary to elementary logic. (1.8.0_20)